# Format a print request on a webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, html, printing

I have created a website to act as a work order creation/fill out system for employees.

Currently work orders are viewed just by looking at a page with a table and various filters so they can order their work orders. However, if they want to print the page, it's a pretty big mess as it gets stretched out across 3 pages, prints the page header, logos, filter buttons, etc.

Is there any way I can make a 'Print' button, or somehow format the way the page looks when it is printed so it can cut out all the extra stuff and just try to keep the table on a single page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`@media print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) css rule. For example:

```
@media print {
    #logo {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding a print css stylesheet to show/hide certain areas of the table or to rescale the container of the table to print sizes.  Here is more information: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/